# How do I get the contents of a specific page, with HTTP, over a socket?

Tags: http

What would I send through a socket connected to *rand.dom.website:80* in order to retrieve the contents of *rand.dom.website/user/22.html*? Including the initial header to send after the socket is first opened.

Comment: Well, obviously you would send a http GET request, just like any other client. Typically one does not use a raw socket for that, but something like `wget` or `curl`. The format of such a GET request is well documented and easy to implement. Or you simply use a network sniffer to capture a "real" request your browser does.

Comment: Search google with keywords "[program_language_you_use] httpClient".